# Is the C++ code converted to C during the compilation process?

Tags: c++, c, compilation

I have read that the original implementation of C++ by Bjarne Stroustrup was using a compiler named `Cfront` that converted C++ to C during the compilation process.

Is this still the case with modern compilers (most of them ?) ?

I couldn't find a good answer using Google (or I couldn't find the right search terms).

**edit**: This is not an exact duplicate because I'm asking for current/modern ones. But both questions & answers apply.

Comment: No, this is not the case anymore.

Comment: To me it sounds logic that compilers translate C++ to native language, usually assembly. notice MicroSoft Managed C++ is translated to byte code (CLR)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Absolutely not. The CFront way of doing things became untenable long ago. There are some C++ constructs with no C interpretation, especially exceptions, and stamping out literal C source for every template instantiation is a bit ridiculous. The entire reason Bjarne stopped making Cfront is because it was impossible.

It is, however, common to lower the code to a more useful IR like LLVM IR, and GCC also has an internal IR, before converting to machine code.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: no. Modern C++ compilers generate native code directly.

There's no reason why you *can't* compile C++ to C, there's just no real reason to do so either any more, so you're adding an extra stage in the compilation process that could just as easily not exist. However, there are still a couple of options if you really need C code output for some reason: the [Comeau C++ compiler](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/) emits C code with the aim of porting your C++ to platforms where a C++ compiler may not exist (which these days, is very few), and [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) uses LLVM as a backend code generator, which has C as one of its many target instruction languages. (edit: of these options, the first is outdated and the second is no longer maintained)

In neither case does the C look anything like the code you put in: it's significantly less readable than machine code would be. The days of converting method calls to function calls with a `this` are certainly long gone - it's very much a case of "compiling" rather than "converting".

Comment: The LLVM C backend was discontinued long ago, because nobody needed or wanted it and it could barely express a tiny subset of LLVM IR, and there are many meaningful C++ constructs with no C equivalent.

Comment: There's no such thing as a language construct with no C equivalent.

Comment: Tell that to LLVM IR function attributes. Or zero-cost Itanium ABI EH.

Comment: Oh sure EH can't be done even remotely *well*. That doesn't mean it can't be done at all. My point is only that you can compile anything to any (Turing-complete) thing if you're stubborn enough. It is not "impossible", it is just a bad idea.

Comment: The definition of "equivalence" used there is meaningless to real-world programs. If I have a C++ program that uses Itanium EH, you cannot write a C program that catches an exception from it, and it's just that simple.

Comment: This is completely true. I don't feel it invalidates the point that C++ can be compiled to C though; only another way in which it's grossly impractical.

Comment: It's not "grossly impractical" if you mean "Half the language features have no possible implementation". That's not "impractical", that's "impossible".

Comment: It's not impossible. I (in this example) could recompile your program from scratch and use expensive exception handling, and the feature would still be supported, just not very well and in a fashion incompatible with any other toolchains.

Comment: You can't recompile my program from scratch because I own the source code and I'm not giving it to you.

Answer (score 0):

No, modern compilers, such as GCC and clang (and others based on LLVM) have generally two parts: back-end and front-end.
Front-end handles compiling source code language into some intermediate representaton, such as LLVM IR.

Back-end generates machine code on target platform, possibly using some optimisations from that intermediate form.